# jquery css strings substrings

Tags: jquery, css, string

```
var currentLeft = $(this).css('left');

if((currentLeft%2)== 0){ thisLeft = currentLeft; }
```

I want to set the variable thisLeft = currentLeft only if the left attribute of the clicked item is divisible by 0.

The problem is that css('left') selects '400px', but im only interested in the 400 part.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentLeft = $(this).css('left');
    currentLeft = currentLeft.replace('px','');
if((currentLeft%2)== 0){ thisLeft = currentLeft; }
```

Comment: There are slightly more efficient ways to do this as posted below. `$(this).css('left').replace('px','');` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left').replace("px", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the px.

```
var currentLeft = $(this).css('left').replace('px','');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try with [`jQuery.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) for example:

### CSS

```
div { padding: 15px;}
p { margin-left:10px; }
```

### HTML

```
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
var position = p.position();
$("p:last").text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
```

will return **left: 15, top: 15**